# Angular select ng-options hell

Tags: angularjs, select, html-select

I'm struggling to understand to documentation for [ngOptions](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)

I have a simple array : `['code1' , 'code2']` and I just want to iterate over and construct option value and label as follow :

What I expect :

```
<select>
    <option value="" class="">All</option>
    <option value="code1">code1.label</option>
    <option value="code2">code2.label</option>
</select>
```

What I've tried :

```
<select ng-model="select" ng-options="option  + '.label' for option in ['code1', 'code2']">
    <option value="">All</option>
</select>
```

What I get :

```
<select>
    <option value="" class="">All</option>
    <option value="0">code1.label</option>
    <option value="1">code2.label</option>
</select>
```

See that values aren't what I want .. I tested almost all possible syntax of the documentation without success.

ps: I've simplified the code, but I use angular-translate to translate the received code and put that translation in the option label.

JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/3ekAj/

Comment: Check again my answer and the comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing what you want is:

```
<select ng-model="select" ng-options="option  + '.label' for option in ['code1', 'code2'] track by option">
        <option value="">All</option>
</select>
```

Fiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ekAj/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's not working. When looking generated source with firebug the value attr of the options are "0" et "1".

Comment: Just so you know, even if the option value says 0 and 1, the actual selected value in the scope will be whatever is defined in the ng-options in this case, "code1" or "code2".

Comment: Thanks your edit saved me ;) This select is linked to a filter for filtering data. with 0/1 values it wasn't filtering anything. Now it's working.

Comment: I was about to answer with this plunker so hopefully it will still help: http://plnkr.co/edit/t2nJIw8NgbzUNmvMMYRF?p=preview